# Running PuTTY via ConEmu hangs until mouse click

Tags: putty, conemu

I run multiple tabs in my ConEmu window (cmd.exe, Admin, WSL) and I've just started trying to run PuTTY through ConEmu also. Whilst it 'works', when I type or copy/paste anything and press Enter, the display doesn't change - it's only when I click the mouse somewhere on the tab that the response is displayed.

When using native PuTTY I don't get this problem.

There may be a PuTTY setting that controls this, but I haven't found it.

I can provide examples if that would help, but I'm hoping someone (@Maximus?) can simply point me at an obvious problem.

Question also asked at https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1911 but no answers there either...

Comment: If using Windows 10, try to replace ConEmu by the [Windows Terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-windows-terminal/).

Comment: I'm on Win 10, but only on version 1803, so Windows Terminal doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why are you not updating to 1909?

Comment: It's a work machine and not under my control.

Comment: Are you sure that ConEmu uses the native PuTTY?

Comment: I'm not sure - that's why I'm asking the question. I BELIEVE it does. It looks like it integrates correctly.

Comment: You could use the full path to be sure.

Comment: Tried the full path, but no different. The issue I raised (referenced above) on GitHub has full details. But the bounty has expired with no answers. Ah well....